# How to design a table when there is irregular relation between fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to design the following relation in a table:

```
PARTNO  OEMNO
--------------    
AA1001  12345
AA1001  67890
AA1002  45678
BB1001  12345
BB1002  12345
```

There is an irregular relation between `PARTNO` and `OEMNO`.

- PARTNO (AA1001) may have more than one OEMNO (12345, 67890)
- REPLACEMENT PARTNO (AA1002) of PARTNO (AA1001) may have different OEMNO (45678, 12345 and 67890)
- REPLACEMENT PARTNO (BB1002) of PARTNO (BB1001) may have same OEMNO (12345)
- OEMNO (12345) may have more than one PARTNO (AA1001, BB1001, BB1002)

**Question:** I am really confused how to create tables and relationships between them so that I can select

- all OEMNO for specific PARTNO and
- all PARTNO for specific OEMNO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have a many-to-many relationship you will need an intermediate table to decompose the relationship. This kind of table has many different names: e.g. "association", "bridging", "junction", "linking". Something like this:

```
create table parts_oems (
partno varchar (10) not null,
oemno varchar (10) not null,
constraint pk_parts_oems primary key (partno, oemno)
)
```

Then you join your table to either parts, or to oems, to determine which of each is associated with the other:-

```
select p.partno, count (po.partno) as oemcount
from
parts p
inner join parts_oems po on p.partno = po.partno
group by p.partno
```

And to determine which oems are associated with partno AA1001 you would write:-

```
select p.partno, o.oemno, o.some_other_columns
from
parts p
inner join parts_oems po on p.partno = po.partno
inner join oems o on o.oemno = po.oemno
where p.partno = 'AA1001'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to establish a relationship table.

```
+------+   +-----+
| PART |   | OEM |
+------+   +-----+
    \         /
   +----------+
   | PART_OEM |
   +----------+
```

- `PART` needs a primary key such as `PART_ID`
- `OEM` needs a primary
  key such as `OEM_ID`
- `PART_OEM` has two `FOREIGN KEY` constraints,
  one pointing to `PART.PART_ID` and the other pointing to `OEM.OEM_ID`